# Replace characters in a series of headlines

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working with feed that I have no control over. I need to replace the first half pipe character in each of a number of headlines with a `<div>` e.g.

```
<h3>New Clause 12 - Monitoring tool | Order | Committees</h3>
```

Changes to

```
<h3>New Clause 12 - Monitoring tool</h3><div> Order | Committees </div>
```

This script works, but it's replacing all instances of `|` and replacing the entire contents of every h3 on the page with the content of the first headline. How can I limit the scope of the script to affect only the first `|` and leave the headlines text content unaltered?

```js
jQuery('h3').html(jQuery('h3').html().replace('|', "</h3><div>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>New Clause 12 - Monitoring tool | Order | Committees</h3>
```

Comment: could you please integrate the code snippet adding more `<h3>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach unfortunately doesn't work as you can't split elements as you're attempting. You can only amend/insert *entire* elements.

To do what you require, select the `h3` element, get the text you require from it and place that in to a new `div` which you insert after the `h3`, like this:

```js
$('h3').each((i, h3) => {
  let $h3 = $(h3);
  let text = $h3.text().split('|');
  $h3.text(text[0].trim());
  $('<div />').text(text.slice(1).join('|')).insertAfter($h3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>New Clause 12 - Monitoring tool | Order | Committees</h3>

<h3>Foo | Bar | Foobar</h3>

<h3>Lorem | Ipsum | Dolor</h3>
```

Answer (score -2):

What about just:

```js
html().replace('|', '</h3><div>').replace(/<\/h3>$/, '</div>')
```

? (If I understood question correctly)